# Custom Parse.Object id

Tags: parse-platform

I'd like to have some Pointers using custom references (for durability).
I know (think?) I can't change the Parse.Object ids using the SDKs.
Is it ok to change the ids using direct mongodb queries ?
Or is there a possibility to tell the framework "for this Class, use this property as the id for Pointers" ?

Just checking.
Thx a lot in advance,

Olivier

Comment: Did you try looking at relations?  http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/#relations

Comment: Do not change the Parse object ID's. Also don't manipulate the parse database outside of Parse. Use Relations as @mogile_oli pointed out.

Comment: I did change the ids directly on mongo right after the document creation (using cloning) and it works like a charm. But you're right: I could have used Relations (but with added complexity). Thx anyway